# Add a button on top of admin orders list in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

I have been struggling to find a hook that allows me to add a button to the top of the woocommerce admin "orders page", but so far unsuccessfully. I have found hooks to add action buttons to the action column, as well as inside each orders page ... but not where I need now.

If there is no hook, then an alternative approach.

More specifically, I attach an image with the place I am referring to

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because this is related to Wordpress and not specific to Woocommerce as Orders are just a custom post type. so the following code will display a custom button on the top zone just after existing fields and buttons:

```
add_action( 'manage_posts_extra_tablenav', 'admin_order_list_top_bar_button', 20, 1 );
function admin_order_list_top_bar_button( $which ) {
    global $typenow;

    if ( 'shop_order' === $typenow && 'top' === $which ) {
        ?>
        <div class="alignleft actions custom">
            <button type="submit" name="custom_" style="height:32px;" class="button" value=""><?php
                echo __( 'Custom', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).* Tested and works.

[image]

---

Continuation: [Run a function on custom button click in woocommerce admin order page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380632/run-a-function-on-custom-button-click-in-woocommerce-admin-order-page/56382355#56382355)